# T1 weighting vs T2 weighting for monitoring a brainstem lession

Tags: cancer, brain, neurology, mri, radiology

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/1-Typical-values-of-relaxation-parameters-T1-and-T2-ms-for-Hydrogen-components-of_tbl1_291346848

I see from the table (various tables actually from diverse papers give different numbers) that T1 weighted images make it easier to distinguish between tissue.

What are the T1 and T2 relaxation times (could we fill the values in the table) of a lesion?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150659/discussion-on-question-by-george-ntoulos-t1-weighting-vs-t2-weighting-for-monito); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.